# Unable to install npm package - error with node-gyp

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, visual-studio-2017-build-tools, durable-rules

All I'm trying to do is installing an npm package called durable. I created a new empty folder and typed in `npm install durable`. The following errors occurred.

[image]

[image: Error thrown in cmd]

I tried everything I could find online, I downloaded the VS build tools that include the c++ build tools as you can see in the following picture.
[image: VS build tools]

I updated npm and node to the latest version, and I have python already installed. I also updated the VS community to its latest version. I don't know what else to do, if any additional info is needed I'd be glad to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Since I tried many solutions from the internet I seemed to change the msvs version. My environment was all good but I set the version to 2017 instead of 2019.
Worked out by running `npm config set msvs_version 2019`

Always keep track of the commands and changes you make.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the error again, you will see it says the node version should be between `v12.11` and less than `v13.11`. And your current version is `v14+`

I am not sure about why `durable` doesn't support the latest node version (published a year ago). You can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) if you are running on linux or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) if you want to use this package only.

Try installing version `v13.0` for node and switch to that version.  I would suggest you to find another package which works well with the latest node version.

Once you are on specific version:

1. Delete node_modules
2. npm i       // for getting the dependencies
3. npm i --save durable

Comment: I don't think the node version is the reason behind the error, it's just a warning. I asked a colleague of mine to try and install durable, it worked for them and they have node v15 and got the same warning but the package was installed.

Comment: So, if this is the case try to check all your dependencies. These issues are generally related to the version. Why don't you update the node to `v15` and just check it. Also, try to check the version of your Visual code, it could be an issue too.